# How can I obtain testnet REP for use on Kovan?

Tags: testnets, kovan, augur

I would like to test the new version of Augur on the Kovan testnet. Where can I obtain testnet REP in order to do so? I found https://faucet.kovan.network/ for Kovan Ether (KETH) but cannot find anything similar for Kovan REP (KREP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go onto V2.augur.net go to the Account Summary page.  Go to the Bottom right of the page under the Transaction section and hit the REP Faucet.

Answer (score 0):

FYI Kovan is now deprecated b/c of the Ethereum Merge!

If you need any free Goerli testETH, Alchemy runs this faucet that's reliable - https://goerlifaucet.com.

You can get more every day if you need.